# How to save frame in opencv python when it detect people

Tags: opencv

Below is some line of code. which detect people using HOG detector and also draw green rectangle when people detect. so i put imshow to save frame. but it save all frame instead of only people detected frame. i want to save frame only when people detect.

```
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = frame[0:420, 400:690]
    found,w=hog.detectMultiScale(frame, winStride=(8,8), padding=(16,16), scale=1.05)
    draw_detections(frame,found):
    timestamp = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")
    cv2.imwrite("person %s.jpg" % timestamp, frame)
    cv2.imshow('people',frame)
    ch = 0xFF & cv2.waitKey(1)
    if ch == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a conditional statement.

Variables `found` and `w` return an array of values if `hog.detectMultiScale()` is able to detect any pedestrian in the frame.

For example, when I tried this code for an image having 4 persons `found` returned an array of the bounding boxes of the 4 persons :

```
found

array([[240,  95, 200, 399],
       [123, 106, 203, 405],
       [203, 294,  84, 168],
       [166, 300,  81, 162]], dtype = int32)
```

`w` returns an array of how probable the detected ones are persons

```
w

array([[0.66943627],
       [0.85531924],
       [0.75906293],
       [0.66459513]])
```

**Code:**

```
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = frame[0:420, 400:690]
    found, w = hog.detectMultiScale(frame, winStride=(8,8), padding = (16,16), scale = 1.05)
    if w:         #--- change is made here ---
        timestamp = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")
        cv2.imwrite("person %s.jpg" % timestamp, frame)
    cv2.imshow('people', frame)
    ch = 0xFF & cv2.waitKey(1)
    if ch == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hi, script run without error, but when it found any people, it stop without save frame and stopped.

Comment: File "people.py", line 30, in <module>
    if found == True:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
 Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: @hk' check the answer now.